# How to parse JSON in ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to parse a JSON response in Ansible.

Here is my JSON response:

```
[
  {
    "serverdb_roles": [
      {
        "name": "apigwsearch"
      }
    ],
    "business_impact": "low",
  },
  {
    "serverdb_roles": [
      {
        "name": "bplatformsearch",
      },
      {
        "name": "devbplatformsearch"
      }
    ],
    "business_impact": "high",
  }
]
```

My Ansible code is this so far:

```
    - name: Parse role_names from JSON
      set_fact:
        role_name: "{{ api_response.json | map(attribute='serverdb_roles') | flatten | map(attribute='name') | list }}"
    
    - name: Print role names
      debug:
        var: role_name
```

This code is able to generate a list of all the roles but I also want corresponding business_impact.

I would be glad, If anyone here can help me generate below JSON response:

```
"role_name": [
        {
            "impact": "low",
            "role": "apigwsearch"
        },
        {
            "impact": "high",
            "role": "bplatformsearch"                                                                                                                                                                          
        },
        {
            "impact": "high",
            "role": "devbplatformsearch"                                                                                                                                                                          
        }
]
```

I'm flexible to use json_query too instead of map if that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the data

```yaml
    review:
      - business_impact: low
        serverdb_roles:
          - name: apigwsearch
      - business_impact: high
        serverdb_roles:
          - name: bplatformsearch
          - name: devbplatformsearch
```

Get the lists

```yaml
  names_impact: "{{ review|
                    json_query('[].[business_impact,
                                    serverdb_roles[].name]') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  names_impact:
  - - low
    - - apigwsearch
  - - high
    - - bplatformsearch
      - devbplatformsearch
```

Unfortunately, it's not possible here to map the filter *product*. Hence, you have to use Jinja

```yaml
  name_impact: |
    [{% for i in names_impact %}
    {{ i.1|product([i.0]) }},
    {% endfor %}]
```

gives

```yaml
  name_impact:
  - - - apigwsearch
      - low
  - - - bplatformsearch
      - high
    - - devbplatformsearch
      - high
```

Create a dictionary

```yaml
  name_impact_dict: "{{ dict(name_impact|flatten(1)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  name_impact_dict:
    apigwsearch: low
    bplatformsearch: high
    devbplatformsearch: high
```

Convert the dictionary to a list (if you have to)

```yaml
  role_name: "{{ name_impact_dict|
                 dict2items(key_name='role',
                            value_name='impact') }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  role_name:
    [
        {
            "impact": "low",
            "role": "apigwsearch"
        },
        {
            "impact": "high",
            "role": "bplatformsearch"
        },
        {
            "impact": "high",
            "role": "devbplatformsearch"
        }
    ]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    review:
      - business_impact: low
        serverdb_roles:
          - name: apigwsearch
      - business_impact: high
        serverdb_roles:
          - name: bplatformsearch
          - name: devbplatformsearch

    names_impact: "{{ review|
                      json_query('[].[business_impact,
                                      serverdb_roles[].name]') }}"
    name_impact: |
      [{% for i in names_impact %}
      {{ i.1|product([i.0]) }},
      {% endfor %}]
    name_impact_dict: "{{ dict(name_impact|flatten(1)) }}"

    role_name: "{{ name_impact_dict|
                   dict2items(key_name='role',
                              value_name='impact') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: names_impact
    - debug:
        var: name_impact
    - debug:
        var: name_impact_dict
    - debug:
        var: role_name|to_nice_json
```